# unable to connect bee-queue to docker container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, queue

for some reason i seem to be having difficulty pointing bee-queue's arena to my other docker image for redis. just wondering if anyone has any experience with this.

this is the pattern of the config i'm using

```
{
  "queues": [
    {
      "hostId": "eyeshade-workers",
      "type": "bee",
      "name": "settlement-report",
      "redis": "redis://redis:3011"
    },
...
```

I have also tried

```
{
  "queues": [
    {
      "hostId": "eyeshade-workers",
      "type": "bee",
      "name": "settlement-report",
      "redis": {
        "url": "redis://redis:3011"
      }
    },
```

```
{
  "queues": [
    {
      "hostId": "eyeshade-workers",
      "type": "bee",
      "name": "settlement-report",
      "url": "redis://redis:3011"
    },
```

here is my redis and arena docker-compose file are here:

```
version: "2.1"

networks:
  ledger:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis:
    container_name: ledger-redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "3011:6379"
    networks:
      - ledger
  arena:
    container_name: worker-arena
    image: mixmaxhq/arena:latest
    networks:
      - ledger
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - eyeshade-worker
    volumes:
      - ./queue/index.json:/opt/arena/src/server/config/index.json
```

but i continuously get this error saying that it is trying to connect to the default :/

```
worker-arena         | (node:42) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
worker-arena         | (node:42) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
worker-arena         | (node:42) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
worker-arena         | events.js:182
worker-arena         |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
worker-arena         |       ^
worker-arena         | 
worker-arena         | Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
worker-arena         |     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
worker-arena         |     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1039:20)
worker-arena         |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1138:14)
worker-arena         | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I found that it had to do with the image (~2 years old) that docker was pointing to, so i built my own, uploaded it to docker hub and then pointed to that in my project and it worked fine. they just have to update the docker image and it should work as far as that, but no, the actual original setup, using their image does not work

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think I solved the issue. In my case, I’m using Bull.js and by default the queue is connecting to localhost and I had another redis.createClient() that I kept focusing on elsewhere until I realized each new Queue() requires the docker redis network instead of localhost. Wasted days on this. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin: Can you post an answer with an example configuration file and latest docker-compose file that works. Thanks